# Apache Spark RDD

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hdfs, clustered-index, apache-spark

Tools : a hadoop cluster (without YARN) with spark 0.9.0.

The ideal situation would be to run a spark program on the namenode over HDFS without communication between the datanodes. The program would do this :

Let's say for the example : on HDFS I have 2 types of data : A and B and my cluster is composed of 3 datanodes.

My goal is to run a program that can work with all the data of A and 1/3B. Datanode1 interact with A and B1 (the first third), Datanode2 with A and B2 (the second third) and Datanode3 with A and B3...
So in order to respect the condition "no communication between machines until the end", I will have to have A and B1 in the memory of datanode1, A and B2 in the memory of ...

The results of the program on each datanode will be agregate at the end.

Is there a way to do that with Spark?

Comment: Why do you want to process all of A in each node?  Sounds to me like your trying to restrict HOW your job will execute, rather than specifying WHAT you job will do, and then letting Spark do the optimizations.  Why do you have this restriction? Security?  Can you be more specific as to what kind of computation your trying to perform?

Comment: Yes sure,I am working on a recommendation algorithm : Matrix Factorization using a stochastic gradient as optimizer. I would like to parallelized my algorithm. 
In fact yes it would be perfect if spark would do the optimizations. My goal is to optimize the computation time. So I don't want to have network communication to access data, that's why I thought restrict job'execution could be an idea.
Very recently I heard that spark could load the data useful for the next computation during the actual computation. So network communication would be "hide" during computation time. Need some sources

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, if you want to do Distributed Matrix Factorization and you are aware that Spark can help to make this fast.  OK well firstly the point of using Spark is not to avoid network load, the point of using Spark for this kind of task is that you can put things into memory and iterate multiple times without having to re-read/write to disk (which is what happens in Hadoop).  Therefore you will get huge speedup than using Hadoop because disk IO is much much slower then most actual computations.

I assume your doing something like this:

http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~rgemulla/publications/gemulla11dsgd.pdf

If you write the code in Scala-Spark, I'd be happy to tell you at what point you need to call .cache().  To be honest I can't tell from skim reading the paper whether or not using the Spark cache can help, but only takes a few mins to refactor code into something optimal without understanding what exactly it is doing.

In short the answer is *no* Spark won't help reduce net IO, but *yes* spark can help reduce disk IO and probably the right candidate for your problem.

Comment: The thing is I can't find the proof of this optimization about the network load. If for each computation the data are not present locally and spark have to wait the network load to do the computation. I will win some time on computation thanks to spark memory (or cache) but loose it during the network load.
Anyway I will continue to read what I can find about this subject. Thanks for your help, I will let know which road I will take to implement it or not ;).